# Trouble using readline() user input with survfit function

Tags: r

I tried looking at past answers, but couldn't find an exact answer. I'm relatively new to R so bear with me.

I'm doing quite a few functions where user input is neccesary. I've gathered that the best way to enter user text is by readlines()

Now the function that i'm mostly concerned with is survfit.

**Reproducible example 1**

```
library (survival)
Survival <- sample (0:100, 100, rep=TRUE)
STATUS <- sample (0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)
variable <- sample (0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(Survival, STATUS, variable )

Graphdata <- survfit(Surv(Survival, STATUS) ~ variable, data=data)
plot <- plot(Graphdata)
```

**What I want to do**

In the survfit function I want to replace the variable with readline() and make the "variable" user inputted.

For example:

```
Graphdata <- survfit(Surv(Survival, STATUS) ~ readlines(), data=data)
```

However, it seems that putting a placeholder won't work because the function is calling data directly from "data" and ignoring the placeholder completely.

I suspect there is a really basic work around.

Cheers

Comment: You should include `library(survival)` at the top of your code, so that people don't have to work out for themselves which package provides the `survfit` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
varA <- sample (0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)
varB <- sample (0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)
varC <- sample (0:1, 100, rep=TRUE)
data <- data.frame(Survival, STATUS, varA, varB, varC)

chosenvar <- readline("\nWhat independent variable do you want to fit?\n")

if(!(chosenvar %in% names(data))) stop(paste("Predictor must be one of", paste(names(data), collapse=", ")))
Graphdata <- survfit(formula(paste("Surv(Survival, STATUS) ~", chosenvar)), data=data) 
plot <- plot(Graphdata)
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Just a minor blip. If I run the entire script in one go, it doesn't pause for input from readlines. I'm sure this is easily fixable?

Comment: `readline()` can only be used in an interactive session, so if you run the whole script, the result will assume that the response to the prompts was `""`.  I think you can get around this if you run your script using the `source()` function.